# Write left header (´ihead´) normal NOT cursively using ´scrpage2´

Tags: scrpage2

**Purpose**

Write left header (´ihead´) normal NOT cursively using ´scrpage2´.

I tried some code but it made no sense.

**Code**

This code is used:

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{totpages}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{Header Left }
\ohead{Header Right}
\ifoot{Footer Left}
\ofoot{Footer Right}
\setheadtopline{0mm}
\setheadsepline{0.1mm}
\setfootsepline{0.1mm}
\setfootbotline{0mm}
```

Footer left and right are written normal.

Header left is written cursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrpage2.sty` defines a command, `\headfont` that controls the font used to typeset headers. This is initially defined as `\normalfont\slshape`, i.e., using the slanted (italic) version of the default font. There are several things you can do to change this:

1. If all you want to do is change only the *inner* header without affecting the outer header, change your `\ihead` command:

   ```
   \ihead{\upshape Header Left}
   ```
2. If you want to change the default for headers (which will change the outer header as well), redefine `\headfont`:

   ```
    \renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
   ```

   You can then use something like `\ohead{\slshape Header Right}` if you want the right header to be italicised.

A couple of (unsolicited) remarks:

1. `scrpage2` has been deprecated in favour of `scrlayer-scrpage`.
2. Technically speaking `\ihead` is the inner header and not *necessarily* the *left* header of the page. You may want to look at Figure 5.1 of the [KOMA-Script](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) documentation for a picture of what's going on. Of course, if your page style doesn't distinguish between even and odd pages, this is irrelevant, but its worth being aware of.